# Crossfilter - Minimum Value by Day

Tags: crossfilter

How do I find the minimum value per day? The dimension being the Days, the group the minimum amount. 
Using the following data as an example -

```
var data = [
  {date: "2011-11-14T10:17:54Z", amount: 10 },
  {date: "2011-11-14T12:20:19Z", amount: 1 },
  {date: "2011-11-14T14:20:19Z", amount: 0 },
  {date: "2011-11-15T06:30:43Z", amount: 10 },
  {date: "2011-11-15T10:30:43Z", amount: 10 },
  {date: "2011-11-15T16:28:54Z", amount: 100 },
  {date: "2011-11-16T18:48:46Z", amount: 100 },
  {date: "2011-11-16T20:53:41Z", amount: 11 },
  {date: "2011-11-16T22:54:06Z", amount: 10 },
];
```

So the results should be -

```
  {date: "2011-11-14T14:20:19Z", amount: 0 },
  {date: "2011-11-15T06:30:43Z", amount: 10 },
  {date: "2011-11-15T10:30:43Z", amount: 10 },
  {date: "2011-11-16T22:54:06Z", amount: 10 },
```

I'm going round in circles trying to work this out and I'm now completely confused so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will get your your absolute minimum. Won't work with filtering though!

```
var data = [
  {date: "2011-11-14T10:17:54Z", amount: 10 },
  {date: "2011-11-14T12:20:19Z", amount: 1 },
  {date: "2011-11-14T14:20:19Z", amount: 0 },
  {date: "2011-11-15T06:30:43Z", amount: 10 },
  {date: "2011-11-15T10:30:43Z", amount: 10 },
  {date: "2011-11-15T16:28:54Z", amount: 100 },
  {date: "2011-11-16T18:48:46Z", amount: 100 },
  {date: "2011-11-16T20:53:41Z", amount: 11 },
  {date: "2011-11-16T22:54:06Z", amount: 10 },
];

var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var dayDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return "" + d.date.substr(8,2); });
var minGroup = dayDim.group().reduce(
  function (p, v) { if(v.amount < p || p === null) p = v.amount; return p; },
  function (p, v) { return p; },
  function () { return null; }
);

console.table(minGroup.top(Infinity));
```

If you want filtering to work, you need to keep a sorted array of all the values found in each array and then add/remove values as data is filtered and unfiltered. Then use this sorted array to figure out your minimum. Something like the following (untested):

```
var data = [
  {date: "2011-11-14T10:17:54Z", amount: 10 },
  {date: "2011-11-14T12:20:19Z", amount: 1 },
  {date: "2011-11-14T14:20:19Z", amount: 0 },
  {date: "2011-11-15T06:30:43Z", amount: 10 },
  {date: "2011-11-15T10:30:43Z", amount: 10 },
  {date: "2011-11-15T16:28:54Z", amount: 100 },
  {date: "2011-11-16T18:48:46Z", amount: 100 },
  {date: "2011-11-16T20:53:41Z", amount: 11 },
  {date: "2011-11-16T22:54:06Z", amount: 10 },
];

var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var dayDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return "" + d.date.substr(8,2); });
var minGroup = dayDim.group().reduce(
  function (p, v) { 
    if(v.amount < p.min || p.min === null) {
      p.min = v.amount;
    }
    p.values.push(v.amount);
    return p;
  },
  function (p, v) {
    p.values.splice(p.values.indexOf(v.amount),1);
    if(v.amount === p.min) {
      p.values.sort(function(a,b) { return a < b ? -1 : 1; });
      p.min = p.values[0];
    } 
    return p;
  },
  function () { return { min: null, values: [] }; }
);

console.log(minGroup.top(Infinity));
```

Comment: Above makes sense, thank you.

How would I go about the array for filtering?

Comment: I've been looking at the example here - http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html Especially the section on maintaining running tallies by year as filters are applied or removed, however I'm not sure how to translate this to what I'm trying to do!

Comment: Updated with an example. Untested. So test well :-) If it doesn't work and you could update the example to work, that would be great.

Comment: It seems to work great! I'm now having problems getting this to a Timechart.     
`.dimension(dayDim)
.group(minGroup)
.valueAccessor(function (d) {
   return d.value.min;
})
`
Thanks for your help with this, I'm slowly getting more confused!

Comment: Ok, I've added what I've done to this fiddle, any pointers would be great! - http://jsfiddle.net/northside45/4dmGv/1/

Comment: In the fiddle, I believe it's an issue that your dimension & group keys are a string while your are defining your x-axis using a time scale. Aside from that, I'm not great with dc.js questions, so hopefully someone else can help you out!

Comment: Hi Ethan, yes it was was my dimension & group key being in the wrong format. It works great now. To pick your brains a little more, what if I now add a 'type' column to the data?

Comment: Should work fine if you just create a separate dimension based on the "type". Is there more to it than that?

Comment: It does seem to be quite right - http://jsfiddle.net/northside45/4dmGv/  Click B and time chart goes, on A it seems ok.

Comment: Yes, quite odd. I suspect there is a bug in the minimum group calculation I provided you. You'll have to work through it to figure out exactly what is happening though. If you console.log() your Crossfilter group, you can right-click on it in the console (at least in Chrome) and assign it to a variable in the console. Then you can click on various things and call .all() or .top() on your group whenever you want to verify it is giving your the proper filtered results. That's probably the easiest way to figure out if the group is behaving properly.